# exporting a parsed file into a text file in python

Tags: python, file

I am parsing a file (.GTF file) and now I have a problem to export it into a text file. So far I have made a list of lists which is EXACTLY like this:

```
pl = [
    [' id "ENS001" ', ' name "EGSB" ', ' Trans "TTP" ', ' ' ],
    [' id "EN02" ', ' name "EHGT" ', ' Trans "GFT" ', ' ' ]
]
```

of course, the length of nested lists is equal (16) and there are 111559 nested lists inside the parent list. As you can see in the example above, nested lists have some pairs and each pair has 2 units which are separated by a tab.

In my text file, each nested list would be a row (only the second unit of each pair) and each item in that will form the columns. The first units are similar in all nested lists and they would be the column names so they are not in the rows. Moreover, I only need the first 8 items (out of 16) of each nested list
Also I use python 2.6.6. I need a file like this.

> ```
> id      name  Trans
>
> ENS001  EGSB  TTP
>
> EN02    EHGT  GFT
> ```

Comment: Any particular error in your code?

Comment: You could loop through your parent list and write the output with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Comment: "I have a problem to export it into a text file."  - what problem?  Are you getting an error message?  One observation, instead of a list of lists, you might be better off with a list of dictionaries, where 'id', 'name', and 'Trans' are keys.  For string formatting, see the `format` method.

Answer (score 4):

First you can split your list with `shlex` to remove the quotes :

```
>>> l=[[shlex.split(i) for i in t i!=' '] for t in pl]

[[['id', 'ENS001'], ['name', 'EGSB'], ['Trans', 'TTP']], [['id', 'EN02'], ['name', 'EHGT'], ['Trans', 'GFT']]]
```

then `zip` your inner list to get the following :

```
>>> z= [zip(*i) for i in l]
[[('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP')], [('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('EN02', 'EHGT', 'GFT')]]
```

then get the rows :

```
>>> rows= [i[1] for i in z]
[('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP'), ('EN02', 'EHGT', 'GFT')]
```

at last write your data in a file :

```
 with open('out.txt','w') as f :
     f.write (' '.join(z[0][0])+'\n')
     for i in rows:
         f.write (' '.join(i)+'\n')
```

---

But as a more efficient way you can put all the list comprehensives to one and refuse from storing them separately :

```
rows=[zip(*i) for i in [[shlex.split(i) for i in t if i!=' '] for t in pl]]
with open('out.txt','w') as f :
     f.write (' '.join(rows[0][0])+'\n')
     for i in rows:
         f.write (' '.join(i[1])+'\n')
```

Comment: when I ran this line it gave me many empty lists: z= [zip(*i) for i in l]

Comment: Of course row = can be reduced to just this single expression: [zip(*j)[1] for j in [[shlex.split(i) for i in t] for t in pl]] ... but that is at the limit of what I'd suggest for list comprehension complexity.

Comment: @JimDennis yes , surely it could be done with more performance . i will update the answer ! but seems that OP faced with an unknown problem !!

Comment: I just updated the lists in the main Q. I think the reason is the empty space at the of each nested lest

Comment: @ Kasra: I replaced with this ****     z = [zip(*filter(None, i)) for i in l] then it worked

Comment: @ali . now i notice . you added an empty list on inner lists . so as you did you can use a filter or as a better way you can use an `if` statement . inside the list comprehensive !

Comment: since I am using python 2.6.6 it might make some problems to use that because of some limitations

Comment: @ali use what ? what problem ? did you try this code ?

Comment: then it gives this error which is related to '\n':    SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character